# Web API is returning wrong JSON when using ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a many to one relation between two models in a .NET Web API Entity Framework project. Each model has a Navigation property to the other model. This as expected generates a "JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected." error.

When I remove the Navigation property from Vendor, I get the expected JSON from the Product controller.

```
var  products = await _context.Products.Include(p => p.Vendor).ToListAsync();
```

The JSON from the Product API is as expected. Without the Navigation property in the Vendor model, I only get the Vendor properties.

Product controller JSON returned without the Navigation property in the Vendor model. The is the JSON I am expecting.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "vendorID": 1,
        "partNumber": "PN001",
        "name": "Big Green Widget",
        "price": 12.95,
        "unit": "Each",
        "photoPath": null,
        "vendor": {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "T100",
            "name": "Test Vendor",
            "address": "123 somewhere st.",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "WA",
            "zip": "98765",
            "phone": "123-123-1233",
            "email": "support@TestVendor.com"
        }
    },
    ...
```

I added the following to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler =
          System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
    });
```

With the Navigation properties in both models I now get the following JSON from the Product controller. When returning a Product it also returns the related Vendor, but also returns a Product collection for the Vendor. This collection is unexpected and is also odd in that it returns a Null product and a random Product from the Vendor's related Products.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "vendorID": 1,
        "partNumber": "PN001",
        "name": "Big Green Widget",
        "price": 12.95,
        "unit": "Each",
        "photoPath": null,
        "vendor": {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "T100",
            "name": "Test Vendor",
            "address": "123 somewhere st.",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "WA",
            "zip": "98765",
            "phone": "123-123-1233",
            "email": "support@example.com",
            "products": [
                null,
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "vendorID": 1,
                    "partNumber": "PN002",
                    "name": "Big Red Widget",
                    "price": 12.95,
                    "unit": "Each",
                    "photoPath": null,
                    "vendor": null
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

### My questions:

- Is this a bug with System.Text.Json?
- If not, how can I get the correct JSON with both Navigation properties?

### Versions:

- .NET 6 and also tested with 7 and 8.
- Matching version Entity Framework.
- The default System.Text.Json, but also tested newer versions from Nuget.

### Models:

```
    public class Vendor
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        // navigation property
        public List<Product>? Products { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int VendorID { get; set; }
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string? PhotoPath { get; set; }

        // navigation property
        public Vendor? Vendor { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would be adding a #null, but setting the reference handler to "Ignore" would not prevent the Vendor.Products from being "touched" by the serializer in the case of lazy loading being enabled, or serializing any related entities that might be tracked otherwise. It would just prevent re-inserting instances of items that it has already inserted to avoid circular reference loops. The alternative is to use the "Preserve" option which would insert a $ref :{id} JSON reference, though this has limitations on whether the deserializer recognizes and reconstructs the reference.

The best option I can recommend to ensure that serialization results in the JSON you expect is to define DTOs for the desired object model and project the entities to the DTOs using `Select()` or `ProjectTo<TDTO>()` (Automapper, or similar with other mapping solutions) This way you can define the Product and Vendor DTOs with just the fields you want serialized, so the VendorDTO would not expose a Products collection, leaving you with clean, predictable JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I do have a DTO solution and a LINQ anonymous type solution, but both add a more work to the project, and if a new property is added in the future I will need to make a lot of edits. I'm hoping to keep the one line solution... `await _context.Products.Include(p => p.Vendor).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Have a look at using a mapper like Automapper, Mapperly, etc. that support mapping via `IQueryable`.  Most of these work automatically by convention so adding a column to a DTO is essentially just that, no "lot of edits", and they map in one line. I.e. `await _context.Products.Where(...).ProjectTo<ProductDTO>(config).ToListAsync();`

Comment: I have a solution using AutoMapper. I more interested in learning more about how the Microsoft out of the box solutions can be used, or what the intent of their solution was.

Comment: About the only other thing that would help is setting the maximum depth for the serializer to 1 or possibly 2. This applies to the entire serialization, not just self-references so it can be a bit of a sledgehammer solution to serialization issues.

Comment: Steve, I tried that, but `MaxDepth` does not limit depth, it raises an error if that depth is exceeded.

Comment: Steve, I "asked" CoPilot and it made the same recombination, but it appears to be completely wrong. Or it at least does not work that way in .NET 6, 7 or 8.

From CoPilot: "For example, if you have an object with properties that reference other objects, setting MaxDepth to 1 will only include the properties of the main object in the JSON output. Any properties of the referenced objects will be ignored. This can be useful in scenarios where you want to limit the size of the JSON output or prevent circular references between objects from causing infinite loops during serialization."

Comment: Yeah, hence "sledgehammer". It will avoid the circular reference issue, but likely will not result in the JSON schema you desire.  Honestly the best way to get a desired, predictable schema out is to project to DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I now better understand this.

- **Is this a bug with System.Text.Json?**

It's not a bug, but not how I understood the documentation. It does not limit cycles between DbSets, but limits cycles between objects. When it detects a cycle back to the same object it sets the property value to Null and stops drilling down.

So, `System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles` is not too useful in my kinds of projects.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,                // this is Product1
        "vendorID": 1,
        "partNumber": "PN001",
        "name": "Big Green Widget",
        "price": 12.95,
        "unit": "Each",
        "photoPath": null,
        "vendor": {            // this is vendor for Product1
            "id": 1,
            "code": "AMZ",
            "name": "AMZ Inc.",
            "address": "123 somewhere st.",
            "city": "Seattle",
            "state": "WA",
            "zip": "98765",
            "phone": "123-123-1233",
            "email": "support@example.com",
            "products": [
                null,           // this is the start of the cycle
                                // back to Product1, so set to null

                {               // This is the first of other
                                // products from Vendor1
                    "id": 2,
                    "vendorID": 1,
                    "partNumber": "PN002",
                    "name": "Big Red Widget",
                    "price": 12.95,
                    "unit": "Each",
                    "photoPath": null,
                    "vendor": null       // this is the start 
                                         // of the cycle
                                         // for Vendor1 back
                                         // to Product1, so 
                                         // set to null
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

---

- **If not, how can I get the correct JSON with both Navigation properties?**

  - Add `[JsonIgnore]` to the Vendor navigation property and use a LINQ Join.
  - Return the Vendor data using a DTO or LINQ anonymous type.
  - or other code solutions...